# How to call a post handler from a ajax render function and pass the value

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, post, datatable, razor-pages

Here's my code. The post handler in the render function does not get called. It keeps going to the GET handler when clicked. The a href tag works fine but i dont want to pass the id value in the url. So, I want to call a post and then do a redirect.

```
@section Scripts {
        <script>
 
            $(document).ready(function () {
               
                    $.ajax({
                        serverSide: true,
                        type: "Get",
                        url: "/SRes?handler=Json",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: OnSuccess,
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            console.log('before send')
                            $('#loadModal').show();
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            console.log('complete send')
                            $('#loadModal').hide();
 
                        }
 
                    });
 
 
            });
 
 
            function OnSuccess(response) {
                console.log(response.data)
 
                $('#myTable').DataTable(
                    {
                        "dom": '<"top"Blf>rt<"bottom"rip><"clear">',
                        buttons: [
 
                            'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                        ],
 
                        scrollY: "400",
                        pageLength: 25,
                        data: response.data,
                        columns: [{
                            className: 'details-control',
                            orderable: false,
                            data: null,
                            defaultContent: ''
 
                        },
 
                        {
                            "data": "Id",
                            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                if (type === 'display') {
                                    /* data = '<a target="_blank" href="/details?id=' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';*/
                                    /*  data = '<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="Details">Test</asp:LinkButton>';*/
                                    data = '<form asp-page-handler=”Details” method=”post”><button type=”submit” class=”btn btn-default”>Save Data</button></form>';
                                }
 
                                return data;
                            }
 
                        },
                        { "data": "name" },
                        { "data": "desc" },
                        { "data": "address" },
                        { "data": "Type" },
                            /* { "data": "status" }*/
                        ],
 
                        initComplete: function (settings, json) {
 
                            $('#myTable').DataTable().columns.adjust();
                            $('#myTable').DataTable().fixedHeader.adjust();
                        },
 
                    });
 
 
                $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
                    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
                    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    var row = table.row(tr);
 
                    if (row.child.isShown()) {
                        row.child.hide();
                        tr.removeClass('shown');
                    }
                    else {
                        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                        tr.addClass('shown');
                    }
                });
 
 
            };
 
            function format(rowData) {
                //var div = $('<div/>')
 
                //div.append(rowData.DOB);
                //div.append(rowData.filingDate);
                //div.append(rowData.type);
                // `d` is the original data object for the row
                return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Case Filing Date:</td>' +
                    '<td>' + rowData.recDate + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Case Type:</td>' +
                    '<td>' + rowData.type + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Date of Birth:</td>' +
                    '<td>'+ rowData.DOB + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '</table>';
 
 
                return div;
            }
 
 
        </script>
    }
```

Here's my code behind. I would like to pass the value of the id to this function. I am using razor pages.

```
  public IActionResult OnPostDetails()
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./cust");
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use html code rather than tag helper in `DataTable`.It will not be generated to html code automatically.When using action in post form,the AntiForgeryToken will not be included in the form.So you need to add it to the forms in `initComplete`.Try to use the following code:
html:

```
<div id="AntiForgeryToken">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
</div>
...
```

js:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable(
                    {
                        "dom": '<"top"Blf>rt<"bottom"rip><"clear">',
                        buttons: [
 
                            'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                        ],
 
                        scrollY: "400",
                        pageLength: 25,
                        data: response.data,
                        columns: [{
                            className: 'details-control',
                            orderable: false,
                            data: null,
                            defaultContent: ''
 
                        },
 
                        {
                            "data": "Id",
                            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                if (type === 'display') {
                                  
                                    data = '<form name="testForm" action="?handler=Details" method="post"><input name="id" hidden value="'+data+'" /><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save Data</button></form>';
                                }
 
                                return data;
                            }
 
                        },
                        { "data": "name" },
                        { "data": "desc" },
                        { "data": "address" },
                        { "data": "Type" },
                            /* { "data": "status" }*/
                        ],
 
                        initComplete: function (settings, json) {
                             $("form[name='testForm']").each(function (index) {
                            $("form[name='testForm']")[index].innerHTML = $("form[name='testForm']")[index].innerHTML + document.getElementById("AntiForgeryToken").innerHTML;
                        })
                            $('#myTable').DataTable().columns.adjust();
                            $('#myTable').DataTable().fixedHeader.adjust();
                        },
 
                    });
```

OnPostDetails:

```
public IActionResult OnPostDetails(int id)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./cust");
            }
```

Comment: I tried this but when i click the button it tries to open a page with this url https://localhost:44308/SearchResults?handler=Details. Gives the error "The Page is not working". HttpError:400

Comment: Hello,I have updated the answer,when using action,the form will not include AntiForgeryToken,so it will get 400.

Comment: this works fine until I click on a column in the datatable to sort. After I do that when I click on the link in the first column it gives me the HttpError:400. How do i fix this?